# Nike Snowboarding website's Jquery/Javascript transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a pretty brief question, do anyone know if there is a Jquery plugin for the following transition: http://www.nikesnowboarding.com/team "Click on the names" or does anyone know how this can be achieved. If one is proficient with Javascript/jQuery, it would much appreciated if you could talk me through achieving this transition.

Comment: You could start by looking at the source code.

Answer (score 2):

They have designed their own custom plugin. You can observe the code [here](http://media.nikesnowboarding.com/browser/js/com.nike.plugins.js)
and use the custom function as per your purpose.

And most of the code that makes the animation is written in browse function.

```
(function($) {

$.fn.Browse=function(settings) { 
  // All the stuff that does animation.
  // What they did is just all event customization.
 }

})(jQuery);
```